# Drupal SEO module - Error on the setup wizrad and on dblog

Tags: google-analytics

I am using all Drupal SEO module , and all recommended module with it.
I do not see any states on the Drupal SEO module reports.

When I am trying to run the setup on admin->config->search->seo tools-> "+Setup wizard", I get the following error:

> Strict warning: Only variables should be passed by reference in
>   seotools_admin_setup() (line 16 of
>   xx/MYusername/public_html/sites/all/modules/seotools/seotools.setup.inc).

In addition, in the dblog, I get many errors after trying to use Drupal SEO:

> TYPE    google analytics reports 
>   DATE    Wednesday, March 26, 2014 - 18:07 
>   USER    Admin   Admin-family 
>   LOCATION    http://www.MySite.com/admin/reports/intel/content?return_type=json&refresh=1
>   REFERRER    http://www.MySite.com/admin/reports/intel/content 
>   MESSAGE Code: 401 - Error: Unauthorized - Message: GDatarequiredAuthorizationLogin Required 
>   SEVERITY    error

Drupal SEO looks like amazing module. Can you help me make it work?
how can I solve this issues the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this helps the next user.

I was having this issue and stepping through your code I noticed it sends a time stamp. Our server time was off by 12 minutes. Once I corrected it everything worked.